# Using the Tumblr API

Tags: python, python-3.x, api-design

It's something new for me working with API, but I really want to create something good. Maybe somebody of you've already worked with Tumblr API (not necessary with Tumblr, it can be Twiter or something else ) and could show me the simplest examples of retrieving of some data. 
P.S: I've read the documentation of using API but I don't know how it works and what I should do to get the data. So if you can, I'll be very happy.
I was advised to use a Tumblr client, but now there is new question. How to install and how to use it in my own code?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the official [Tumblr client](https://github.com/tumblr/pytumblr)

If you want to write a client from scratch take a look in [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library.
A simple `GET` request will be something like this `requests.get('https://api.github.com/user')`

Comment: Thanks, but how should I use this Tumblr client?
How to install and how to use in my own code?

Answer (score 0):

Use [pip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) to install python packages.

After installing... From the shell, run:

```
pip install pytumblr
```

or

```
pip3 install pytumblr
```